# Sonar catch incorrectly in this case? (S2589)

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I have following code and Sonar supposes it is about code smell ([2589](https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-2589)):

```
FontWeight Method1(object value)
{
    return value is bool isBold && isBold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
}
```

I guess Sonar want me to remove the `isBold`, but the logic will not correct any more. Is it an incorrect catch from Sonar?

Comment: As far as the warning goes, assuming you have some version of the above that actually does compile, the warning may simply be a limitation of Sonar with respect to the newer `is` declaration syntax. You don't seem to have a redundant element in a Boolean expression; try putting parentheses around the elements to make explicit what the precedence is, to help Sonar get it right.

Comment: Hi @PeterDuniho, I tried to put parentheses but it's still there, the code is: `return ((value is bool isBold) && (isBold)) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;`

Comment: I don't use Sonarqube so can't test. But I meant for you to try `return ((value is bool isBold) && isBold) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;`. If that doesn't fix it and you really don't want to just suppress the warning, you can move the conditional aspect into a helper method.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree with you

Comment: What about `return value is true ? FontWeight.Bold : FontWeight.Normal;`

Comment: Wow that works @pinkfloydx33, I just figured out it's the *Constant pattern* in C# 7.0, it resolves my issue. Thanks.